How to remove algae from an outdoor water fountain made of stainless steel with a mirror finish (chrome?) without scratching the finish?
I don’t want to scratch it. I am worried about using vinegar as it has been many times suggested.

The go to product for removing algae outside is outdoor bleach.

You use a non-abrasive cleaner, like a plastic scrubby.

If it is stainless steel then bleach is not going to have any effect on it.  And vinegar is even milder.
There are several grades of stainless, some of which will rust in constant contact with water and air.  It would appear that you have a better grade, since it is not showing any signs (even spots) of rust.
Go ahead and use either.  If you are still worried, then use vinegar.  Even diluted vinegar will have some effect,  it may take longer and require more elbow grease.

I'd use a pressure washer spraying plain tap water. No chemicals, no abrasives, no worries, and it will be clean as a whistle.
And if you want to prevent algae going forward, get an algaecide from your local pool and spa dealer. Follow label directions.
